# How to use autowire in symfony flex application?

Tags: symfony-flex, symfony-3.4

with symfony 3.4 i am able to use `autowire` in my application but when i am using same `services.php` in symfony flex application its giving me error as

> Cannot autowire service "Services\xxx": argument "$key" of method
>   "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.

I am new to symfony flex.

Comment: Maybe you should share the `services.php`?